# Fully Protected SQL Server 2005 Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed an application on my machine and it installed an instance of SQL Server 2005 Express. I can connect to this instance from SSMS using Windows Authenticating mode and have found a few databases there installed by that installer. But I have no rights to do anything in that instance.

So there are two logins in the `Instance --> Security --> Logins`:

1. `sa`
2. `BUILTIN\Users`

`sa` is password protected although sysadmin.
`BUILTIN\Users` has server roles = public, just public. so this user can not do anything.

This means this instance is only valid for that app and no one can use this instance for any other database.

I need to know, if there is some way to make the `BUILTIN\Users` sysadmin. Or do some trick to use this instance.

Anyways, it is using memory and HDD space.

Comment: Only users with the level of permission can grant the requested level of permission. It sounds like you'd need to get the sa password and then grant with that. Having said that, granting sysadmin to that group sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Aaahhhhh, its my local machine instance. and I can not do anything with this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand wrote a great article awhile back that demonstrated a method to gain access using "PsExec" from SysInternals if you have local admin access to your local machine.

You can reference this tip from MSSQLTIPS that will walk through the steps to see if this will solve your problem.
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Once you gain access, you can assign yourself SysAdmin access to the SQL Server.